# How to launch function when screen in reached in TabNavigator ? [REACT NAVIGATION]

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

The problem is that the functions *constructor()* and *componentDidMount()* are called when the tab navigator is loaded. 
And I need to call function each time the user reachs the screen named *myScreeen* for example
How we can do that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found hack :

```
    <Navigator
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
  const getCurrentRouteName = (navigationState) => {
    if (!navigationState) return null;
    const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
    if (route.routes) return getCurrentRouteName(route);
    return route.routeName;
  };
  let currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
  if(currentRoute == "A") {
     console.log("TRIGGER")
}}/>;
```

And then you listen to the log in your component, like this :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let slf = this;
    let log = console.log;
    console.log = function(txt) {
      if(txt == "TRIGGER") {
        slf.myFunction();  // CALL HERE YOUR FUNCTION
      } else {
        log.apply(console, arguments);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

React-Navigation provides an [onNavigationStateChange](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/0f6b32868796a92a2a77a224b9140d6d5e02184e/docs/api/navigators/Navigators.md#onnavigationstatechangeprevstate-newstate-action) props that you can use to invoke methods when navigation state change. The [screen tracking example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/screen-tracking) showed you an example where you can get the new state's key and route name.

From the example, in the `getCurrentRouteName` method, you can do `const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];` once you retrived the `route`, you can find out the key and route name by calling `route.key` and `route.routeName`.

Comment: there is problem, can you help please (commented line) ? Thank you so much
https://jsfiddle.net/gdydL0p4/

Comment: @ScoopDevek For that, I don't see a direct solution through the current React-Navigation implmenetaion, my colleague have pointed to this addon: https://github.com/satya164/react-navigation-addons, and you can read about the discussion around this feature in here: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51

Comment: Thank you, I will post the solution if I find